# Can I prematurely generate a "let's start this discussion in chat" link?

Tags: feature-request, comments, chat

There are some occasions where comments become a bit like a discussion, and the link to start a conversation in chat comes up. And it's all neat: It's an archived chat specific to that question.

But sometimes that link doesn't come up for a long while, possibly because comments don't fit a very particular pattern. In that situation, is it possible to prematurely generate a link to an archived chat specific to that question?

And if not, would it be a good idea to make that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may not understand what you mean by "an archived chat specific to that question" in the second paragraph. Specifically, I'm confused by the word "archived." Could you give an example?

If you're just looking to start a new chat that will become archived, you don't have to wait for the system. You have more than enough rep to go to the chat main page and create a room manually, then return to the comments and post a direct link. All Stack Exchange chats are permanently saved.

Comment: All chats are archived, by design, so I'm not sure that's the bulk of the request. It's about starting the chat discussion *before* the system decides to intervene in the emerging "comment-discussion".

Comment: For example http://superuser.com/questions/343382/how-to-copy-one-file-to-a-folder-and-all-its-subfolders-in-windows-7/343384#343384  has a link to a chat that got generated, and it's specific to that question. http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1518/discussion-between-barlop-and-paul "Discussion between barlop and Paul

Imported from a comment discussion on superuser.com/questions/343382/"

Comment: I don't see how, if at all, my answer doesn't address your use case. Simply go to chat and click the "create new room" button, then manually post a comment that contains a link to the room. Are you actually asking for the system to do what it's already doing, but earlier? @barlop

Comment: well i'll test what you suggest here, and see how it goes

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1526/lordtorgbarlop

Comment: yeah looks basically equivalent functionality

Comment: No it's not quite there 'cos the room displays in the main channels as active.  I don't want it to display there..

Comment: as torg just pointed out in that room.. in both cases it comes up in the list of active rooms