# How to manually move a comment conversation to a chat?

Tags: support, feature-request, comments, chat

Is it possible to manually move a discussion in comments to a chat room? I just got the usual message that I should move the conversation to a chat.

> Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to
>   automatically move this discussion to chat?

But for some reason, it failed to move it. I got a message saying that the move has failed. It's not appearing again. So I was wondering if it's possible to move it manually? Why does it have to be done automatically?...

I'm not interested in having the above message appear automatically after this or that many comments, etc. as [some users](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/3548/can-i-prematurely-generate-a-lets-start-this-discussion-in-chat-link) have discussed. That's really good! But I want to be able to do it at will, preferably by a simple click of a button next to a comment. I don't want to wait for some automatic system to prompt for moving the conversation.

Comment: Is there a chat between the OP and another person? I tried to move my comments to chat, but it would not move either. I am guessing if a chat already exists for the user, another one can not be created. One chat per question? I would think new chat should get migrated over to existing chat. Seems like an unforeseen situation and an enhancement may need to be made for this use case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always just [start a chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/new) if you want to. This won't automatically insert the previous messages from the comments, but it will allow you to start a chat with any user who has at least 20 rep.

If the user has an existing chat account, you can even go to their chat profile and select "start a new room with this user", which will automatically invite them to the room.

Comment: How can I see if a user has a Chat profile? How can I search for a user on Chat?

Comment: Never mind, I got it. For example, if I want to see if you have a Chat profile I can simply click on your user name here. Then, under Accounts, I can click "view more" and see if Chat appears in the list. To search for users on Chat I can head over to http://chat.stackexchange.com/ and click on "users" on the top menu and then enter "TRiG" in the "filter users" search field on the right. He has a profile on Chat. I can see that you don't have a profile.

Comment: @Sammy I do have [a profile on chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/1768/nhinkle).

Comment: You may need to sort by "all" instead of "currently online" when searching for users.

Comment: Sorry about that! :) Yes, I found you after changing to "all". Thanks! But the Chat profile doesn't show up under Accounts?...

Comment: @Sammy correct, it does not.

Comment: So the way I would do this is, I would go to the Chat, find the user with whom I wish to start a conversation with, and then copy the URL of that chat room, go back to the original question on SU, and post a link in the comment section?...

Comment: @Sammy you could just start a chat room and give the link to the user. Anybody can just create a new chat room; you don't _have_ to invite the user. If you do invite the user, they'll automatically get a notification though.

Comment: Alright, I'll try that next time. Thanks!